# Django serve static index.html with view at '/' url

Tags: django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I have my index.html in /static/ folder. My django app is running ok when i try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html
```

But i want to acces index.html by url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I wrote a view and it works:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

I also added to urls.py(this lets me serve static like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/style.css`):

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True
        }),
```

But i think there is a way to do what i want without TemplateView.

Any suggestions? Thanks. My django version is: **Django 1.5**

**EDIT**:

The reason i placed index.html into static: i want to make Phonegap compatible django app, so after proper coding, all i have to do is --> **make .zip from static** folder and upload it to Phonegap as mobile app. Easy and clean.

Comment: Why don't you want a TemplateView? It's there for this reason.

Comment: I just thought there is a way to serve in without a view at all.

Comment: Use the [flatpage app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) then.

Comment: `I have my index.html in /static/ folder` - this is your problem. `/static/` is not for html files.

Comment: It's static html, not template. Just peace of static code without django tempalte tags and etc.

Comment: Then really, use the FlatPage app, it's designed for this exact usecase.

Comment: OK, maybe next time i will use it. Including another app to django is not worse one page serving.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can serve `static/index.html` for development like this:

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += url(
        r'^$', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve', kwargs={
            'path': 'index.html', 'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

But for production you should configure your `nginx` (or other frontend server) to serve `index.html` file for `/` location

**UPDATE**

I want to explain the case you should do like this. For example your django app is only admin and api view, but client interacts with a single page app (Ember, Angular, whatever). So you project has at least two subprojects, one with your main django app and the second is a client app with all html/js/css stuff. It is very convenient to have client scripts separate from django backend, it allows your frontend developers to do their job and avoid django existence (someday it can be moved to the distinct repo).

So in this case you get the following build workflow:

1. Run client app sources watcher to rebuild your scripts/styles/templates (`brunch watch`, `grunt` job or `gulp` watch task)
2. Collect static with django for production
3. Make sure you have urlpatterns fix for developments and right nginx config for production

Here is my `urls.py` example

```py
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
    url(r'^(?:index.html)?$', 'serve', kwargs={'path': 'index.html'}),
    url(r'^(?P<path>(?:js|css|img)/.*)$', 'serve'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do you deal with HTML5 History API and serving from a src folder? I build my Angular apps so that they are served from src during dev. I amended the patterns so that the index.html is caught by a catch all URL pattern and placed this before the pattern for assets. Seems to work. But I'd like to serve js/css/img from templates/src. Tried changing the doc. root but it doesn't work (can't paste code into replies argh)

Comment: @Howie is it open source project? Could you show me what you have?

Comment: Hi @Anton. Sorry for late response. I've created a boilerplate on Github to use your recommendation above. Perhaps you could provide a hint? The SPA works outside of Django, but is not served through Django https://github.com/howieweiner/django-angular-boilerplate. Thnx

Comment: From the Django docs Warning

This view will only work if DEBUG is True.

That's because this view is grossly inefficient and probably insecure. This is only intended for local development, and should never be used in production.

Answer (score 45):

You don't need to subclass `TemplateView` in this case. You can use `TemplateView` directly in your url conf, as long as `index.html` is in your templates directory.

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name="home"),
]
```

Comment: So there is no way to serve static HTML file without passing it through template renderer?

Comment: The [`views.serve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve) helper is intended for development only. You shouldn't use Django for serving static files in production. Use your web server e.g. Apache or Nginx to serve static files.

Comment: @Alasdair  Could you explain why not?  I mean everybody says this, but they never say why.  If you're serving an SPA that ships its entire view apparatus in one pre-compiled payload, it doesn't seem so bad to just let Django serve it up.  Any given visitor only loads it one time. But if there are reasons that don't predate modern SPA architecture, I'd be very interested to know what they are.

Comment: @npskirk because it incurs a CPU cost that is more significant that simply using Nginx.

Comment: @npskirk The main reason not to use it in production is security, not efficiency. The [warning in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) is pretty explicit.

Comment: don't forget to add `from django.views.generic import TemplateView`

Comment: Isn't another reason for serving static file using the web server directly that it allows the client to cache those resources?

Comment: @Feuermurmel the client can cache a resource if the correct cache headers are set. It doesn't matter whether the page is served by Django or another web server.

Comment: @Alasdair You are right. But by default web servers will set those headers while web application frameworks won't (because they are designed for dynamic content).

Comment: @Feuermurmel I don't think that web servers will set those headers by default - it's not a safe assumption that index.html isn't going to change, just because it's a file on disk. In any case, I think we're going off topic here.

Answer (score 4):

Check out my long explanation of how to serve *index.html* on `/` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40525157/544059) (or extended as a [blog post](https://metakermit.com/2016/simple-way-to-set-up-django-a-spa-frontend-on-heroku/)). That solution alone might not be sufficient, however, if you want to have a full-fledged SPA served by Django (because you need frontend routing).

I've been playing with different methods for routing `/static/` to `/`, forwarding all requests to the frontend, finding *index.html* files. In the end I found the best method to solve all of this was not by tweaking *urls.py*, but as an extension of WhiteNoise that I released as [django-spa](https://github.com/metakermit/django-spa) (installation instructions in the README).

You can find some of the related discussion in this [WhiteNoise issue](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/issues/12).

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your static HTML file in an iframe defined in a templated HTML file.  With some style tweaks  can make the iframe 100% width and height.

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Templated HTML</title>

        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border-width: 0;
            }

            iframe {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border-width: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ content }}
        <iframe src="{% static 'main/html/test.html' %}"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi let say array name graph=['A.html','B.html'] then {% for i in graph %}
<iframe width="47%" height="700" src="{% static '{{i|safe}}' %}" ></iframe>
{% endfor %}

Any ideas to edit the src links, when i run it return **A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.**

Answer (score 3):

you can create templates directory, put the html  there and then render it from views.py

```
    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'my_app/index.html', context={})
```

dont forget to set the templates_dir in the settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    ...
```