# how to access a file from root of django project

Tags: python, django

I have a .html file. I want to access file like this (http://my_site_name.com/somefile.html) from my Django website.
I do not want to use static folder.
thanks

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989341/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that, you should serve it using urls and views or directly using `TemplateView`.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
     (r'^somefile/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='somefile.html')),
]
```

Comment: my file has static content and never change (and no need to render as html), is there any way to not use template?

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to use static folder, why not just bind this file to a `view` function , treat it as a template, and write route for it?  You can achieve this by using `TemplateView`.

If you do not want to touch template either, there have another solution.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings


def staticView(request):
    with open(settings.BASE_DIR+"/a.html") as fp:
        return HttpResponse(fp.read())

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('a.html',staticView)
]
```

As you can see, codes above just read a html file, and make HTTP response using file contents. No `Template` or `static folder`, you can put your file into any directory which can be accessed.