# How to load iframe in Python Django?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, iframe

I have a HTML file that store in different folder with django.

Below is my HTML code that I run under Python Django:

```
<body>
{% load staticfiles %}
{{graph|safe}}
{% for i in graph %}
<div class="box">
<iframe width="47%" height="700" src="{{i|safe}}"  frameborder="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen align="left" ></iframe>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

The output for graph is

```
["a.html","e.html","I.html"]
```

So the iframe create is 3 for this case, I able saw there is 3 box of the iframe generated but fail to see the content. Anyone can share ideas?

Comment: can you post what is getting rendered in `src` of `iframe` do view-source of output page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that the html files you're trying to serve do not have a url. You could do either of these two options:

**Option 1:** Add a url for each html file in your `urls.py`. Something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('a.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="a.html")),
]
```

**Option 2:** You could serve them as [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/). There is some discussion about that in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989341/django-serve-static-index-html-with-view-at-url). This would be better suited if you don't know the names of your html files beforehand.

Comment: Hi I have try both but the contain still not able show out, any ideas on this?

Comment: Hi let say array name graph=['A.html','B.html'] then {% for i in graph %} <iframe width="47%" height="700" src="{% static '{{i|safe}}' %}" ></iframe> {% endfor %} Any ideas to edit the src links, when i run it return A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Answer (score -1):

iframe is not supported in HTML5. U should use embed instead of iframe, but if u want to use iframe then maybe u should use a lower version of html. check this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: I have try the example in the link, and have a try, but it refuse to connect if i using django package, but if i used stand alone HTML it work well

Comment: iframe is recommended for HTML files